# SSRS throwing an error when subreports have no data

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

I have an SSRS master report which includes multiple sub reports (with few parameters passed from Main report, sub reports have graph and tablix)

One of the combination of parameter's on sub reports results in no results in dataset on sub-reports. I have set no data message on these individual sub reports.

The problem is that when i run the main report with this combination it doesn't display this no data message but instead throws "**An internal error occurred on the report server. See the error log for more details. (rsInternalError)**" message

When I run these individual reports with same combination of parameters, I get the no data message displayed correctly.

I tried my best to find solution online, but couldn't find any.

Any help would be useful. Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My sub report was not having a data-set and as a result it was throwing an error on main report.

I added a dummy data set in my sub-reports, using an existing data-source with query.

```
SELECT ' ' AS DUMMY
```

and then added text box in my sub-report to display this dummy field.

```
=First(Fields!DUMMY.Value, "DUMMY")
```

and it worked after that. Basically I am forcing SSRS to display sub-report even if there is no data.